# What does drw-r--r-- mean in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

So, I tried to search it but what does **`drw-r--r--`** mean in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

Answer (score 5):

The first letter "d" means *directory*. All following letters are permissions for different users. "r" stands for *reading*, "w" for *writing*, and "x" denotes if file is *executable*.

First 3 letters behind "d" are permissions for *owner*, other 3 for *group*, and last 3 for *others*. The permissions for certain file/directory can be seen in Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) using

`ls -l`

command. They can be changed using `sudo chmod` command (chmod has to be used with sudo).

More can be read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

So in your case this means that what are you looking at is a Directory that the owner (assuming that's you) has the permission to read and write, all other users can only read.

Comment: Oh, is see. Thank you for the clear explaination, you are a lifesaver  :)